# How can I make this Makefile more generic?

Tags: c++, makefile

I'm brushing up on C++ by completing many small programs, each contained in a single cpp file. I also want to learn a little bit more about Makefiles, and decided to write a Makefile that will compile all of my little programs and produce an executable per program. With my current Makefile, I have to:

1. Append the name to the end of "BINARIES"
2. Copy the repeated target and replace the target name with the binary name

**How can I edit this Makefile to be even more generic, so that I can simply append the name of my new program to the end of "BINARIES" and not have to continue to copy and paste the repeated targets?**

```
    BIN=./bin/
    SOURCE=./src/
    CXX=g++
    CXXFLAGS=-g -c -Wall
    BINARIES=sums-in-loop sum-in-loop sum-of-two
    RM=rm -f

    all: sums-in-loop sum-in-loop sum-of-two

    sums-in-loop:
        $(CXX) $(CXXFLAGS) $(SOURCE)$@.cpp -o $(BIN)$@ 

    sum-in-loop:
        $(CXX) $(CXXFLAGS) $(SOURCE)$@.cpp -o $(BIN)$@ 

    sum-of-two:
        $(CXX) $(CXXFLAGS) $(SOURCE)$@.cpp -o $(BIN)$@ 

    clean:
        $(RM) $(BIN)*
```

Comment: @OMGtechy not really. This isn't a "How can I make my code better/faster", he is asking about one specific aspect.  Shouldn't be moved to Code review.

Comment: `CXX` and `RM` are already set by make to the exact same strings you're providing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The usual way is to use pattern rules:

```
BIN=bin
SOURCE=src
CXX=g++
CXXFLAGS=-g -Wall
BINARIES=sums-in-loop sum-in-loop sum-of-two
RM=rm -f

all: $(addprefix $(BIN)/,$(BINARIES))

$(BIN)/%: $(SOURCE)/%.cpp
    $(CXX) $(CXXFLAGS) $< -o $@ 

clean:
    $(RM) $(BIN)/*
```

Comment: I get "*** No rule to make target '%.c', needed by 'bin/sums-in-loop'.  Stop.". Is there a way to make the target dynamically have the prefix bin/ as well, to satisfy the target needed? I'm messing with your solution right now, but haven't gotten it to run yet.

Comment: @Chris is right about patterns, but there are a few things in that example that don't work. `SRC` should be `SOURCE`, `.c` should be `.cpp`, and `addprefix` strips the leading `./` from `BIN` which breaks the pattern rule, which can be fixed by declaring `BIN=bin/` without the leading `./`

Comment: I had to also remove the "-c" from "CXXFLAGS" as I was making object files, not executables. Thank you to both of you!

Comment: This makefile defeats the purpose of makefiles: it always does a full rebuild of an executable. And no auto-generated header dependencies.

Comment: @MaximEgorushkin: It only rebuilds the binaries for which the source is newer.  Each binary can only be build from a single source, true, but that is what the OP appears to want.

Comment: @MaximEgorushkin I don't think it defeats the purpose of makefiles but can admit it doesn't use them to their fullest potential. My use case was going through small practice problems, where each problem was limited to one file. That's what brought this up, regardless if you agree with it, it was something I did not know how to acheive and my google foo wasn't helping.

Answer (score 0):

With loops in Makefile, you can do something like :

```
$(foreach bin,$(BINARIES),$(CXX) $(CXXFLAGS) $(SOURCE)$(dir).cpp -o $(BIN)$dir;)
```

You can find some info --> http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Foreach-Function